# the variable changes for all Telegraf.js users

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I am developing a language selection function for my telegram bot written in telegraf.js, language variable changes for all users and this needs to be fixed

```
bot.start(async (ctx) => await ctx.reply("Выберете язык / Choose language: ",{
    reply_markup:{
        inline_keyboard:[
            [ { text: " Русский", callback_data: "ru" }, { text: " English", callback_data: "en" } ],
        ]
    }
}))
let lang;
bot.action('ru',() => lang = "ru");
bot.action('en',() => lang = "en");
```

i tried adding acync/await in various places but it did not help

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are modifying a global variable that is stored on the server-side. Note that the code you wrote will be only one instance running for all users, it doesn't spawn a new instance for each user, meaning that global variables are shared.

To store different data for each user, you should use the [`session`](https://telegraf.js.org/functions/session.html) middleware. Note that by default it only stores the data in-memory. To persist it, make sure to check the linked doc page.

Here's how to use it:

```js
const { Telegraf, session } = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN);
bot.use(session());

bot.action('ru', (ctx) => {
  ctx.session.language = 'ru';
});
bot.action('en', (ctx) => {
  ctx.session.language = 'en';
});

// To test it
bot.command('test', (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.session.language === 'ru') {
    ctx.reply('Здравствуйте!');
  } else {
    ctx.reply('Hello!');
  }
});
```

Additionally, if you are using TypeScript, here is how you'd add static types:

```js
import { Telegraf, session, type Context } from 'telegraf';
import type { Update } from 'telegraf/types';

type SupportedLanguage = 'ru' | 'en';

interface MyContext<U extends Update = Update> extends Context<U> {
    session: {
        language: SupportedLanguage;
    };
}

const bot = new Telegraf<MyContext>(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN);
// I'm honestly not sure why the `as string` part is required, but my code doesn't work without it
bot.use(session({ defaultSession: () => ({ language: 'en' as string }) }));
```

and the rest of the code remains the same